# Ball from one urn to another one to... - Name of urn model

Tags: probability

I'd like to know the name of the urn model such that at the beginning there are for example **four urns**, the first one with 10 balls (1 red and 9 blue), and each of the other ones with 9 blue balls. Then I draw a ball from the first one and put it in the second one, then I draw a ball from the second one and put it in the third one. Finally I draw a ball from the third one and put it in the fourth one.

Comment: There's something called the Ehrenfest urn model, I don't know whether that's what you've got.

Comment: Hello @GerryMyerson I read that the Ehrenfest model consists of two urns. https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Reversible_Computing/Lq_MBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=multiple+urns+model&pg=PA51&printsec=frontcover

Comment: OK. Well, there may not be a name for the model you describe. There's also a Polya urn model, but I don't think you want that either. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem talks about some other models, but doesn't give them names.